# Surface and Plane : Are they different in 3D vector?

Tags: geometry, definition, surfaces

Hopefully it's a question.

In 2D geometry the graph of an equation involving *x* and *y* is a curve
in the plane. In three-dimensional geometry an equation in *x*, *y*, and *z* represents a *surface* in space.

I couldn't understand about the *Surface*, here's a picture I modified through ms. paint:

[image]

There's a thing that is even confusing me :

[image]

Is this a plane ? The thing is its width is over increasing along the *y-axis* while it should be *y=0* Then what would I call it in my B-picture above?

Comment: A plane is a surface whose points are aligned according to two directions.

Comment: Well now that's confusing me even more :D, btw if point *(x,y,z)* should be on the surface, then picture C is the surface right? or is it, picture C is a plane and surface as well?

Comment: Any connected bidimensional subdomain is a surface. But a plane has the same normal for each of its points. I can't tell from your picture if C is a plane, for sure it seems a surface. Figure 5 is a plane (both x and y are not limited for a plane).